# Use ULID with symfony and executeQuery

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

With symfony
I'm trying to make a delete request on an id in ULID format, but it doesn't work and I don't get an error

```
$this->connexion->executeQuery('
                DELETE FROM plant_periode WHERE plant_id = :plantId
            ', [
                'plantId' => $plant->getId()
            ]);
```

```
/**
 * Trait UuidTrait
 */
trait UlidTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="ulid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="doctrine.ulid_generator")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * getId
     */
    public function getId(): ?Ulid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I try with

```
$this->connexion->executeQuery('
                DELETE FROM plant_periode WHERE plant_id = :plantId
            ', [
                'plantId' => $plant->getId()->toBinary()
            ], [
                'plantId' => ParameterType::BINARY
            ]);
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution :

```
$this->connexion->executeQuery('
                    DELETE FROM plant_plant WHERE HEX(plant_source) = :plantId
                ', [
                'plantId' => bin2hex($plant->getId()->toBinary())
            ]);
```

Maybe you have better?